# Cache server for C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am using System.Runtime.Caching in windows application(c#)

This works fine for single machine. Now I want to share cache between multiple instances running on different computers.

So I am thinking of using MEMCACHED or Hazelcast IMDG

Any c# implementation or idea/ results how this works. Please note I am doing this for windows application. Any other suggestion is  also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Redis all the way!

Comment: Redis cache is the best option in this case.

Comment: Redis is one of the poor option, when you need Querying ability

Comment: If you really need caching only, try CacheManager.NET (http://cachemanager.michaco.net) which supports in-memory, redis or memcached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using In memory cache, needs clear understanding of following use cases:

1. Is it only a memory dump ?
2. Does it needs Querying ability, like `IQueryable`, provided by the frameworks like Entity Framework for the `Sql Server` ?

If its only in memory dump then `Redis, MemCache` are fine, as they just store data in the memory as binary, de-serialized once fetched at the client location, which is not good if you are querying lots of data and want processing like filtering, sorting, pagination to be done at the source.

In case `IQueryable` processing is required, then check out `ApacheIgnite.Net. Hazelcast and ScaleOut`, out of them I find Apache Ignite to be most advanced, since it just doesn't support the `Expression trees, via IQueryable`, but also `Ansi Sql`, which is a very big advantage over other Cache

Also another point remains, why not replace Sql Server or similar database by a modern in memory system like `VoltDB` or Document db like `Raven`, as they are much faster, well integrated and completely exclude the need to separate Cache

Comment: I am using MySql. And migrating is not possible at this point of time. I need only a memory dump.

Comment: Consider [Apache Ignite.Net](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs), which in my understanding is much better option than Redis. Will be even compatible for the future requirements.

Comment: Thanks I am checking on Apache Ignite

Comment: Ignition.Start();
                var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
                {
                    // Register custom class for Ignite serialization
                    BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration(typeof(TempCounterSale))
                };
                IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);
                ICache<DataTable, TempDt> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<DataTable, TempCounterSale>("TempDt");
                cache = dtable;

Comment: Not able to put datatable in Ignite Cache

Comment: @JohnyBravo This is incorrect, Ignite and other professional Cache have a design of `ICache<ICacheEntry<TK,TV>>`, so each entry has a key and value, you cannot store whole `DataTable`, as you have been doing in in memory Cache. You have to break DataTable into DataRows, then store each Row with separate Key

Comment: Ideally what you need is concrete class instead of `DataTable, DataRow` when you work with Typed Cache like Apache Ignite

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `Redis` for caching purpose.
Here's a good c# library for Redis: [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.RedisvQIT6ziBGic0mGF5O3Q&sig2=mQ913Tg896alLMSax6LuoQ)

Comment: Using Redis, will it be installed as windows service?

Comment: How easy it would be to install it on client location having different Windows OS versions

Comment: Shall not be an issue, but check out this might be a paid client, one by Stack Overflow is free

Comment: @JohnyBravo you can use https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/ for redis server and then connect to application using connection string.

Comment: hmm but application is desktop based. So internet connectivity is not for sure

Comment: in that case you can easily install it on client's desktop. redis supports various platforms.keep in mind that redis uses RAM to store data so make sure enough ram is available for redis.